# Python: exclude outer wrapping element when getting content via css/xpath selector

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried this code to get the HTML content of element `div.entry-content`:

```
response.css('div.entry-content').get()
```

However, it returns the wrapping element too:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>**my content**</p>
    <p>more content</p>
</div>
```

But I want just the contents, so in my case: `<p>**my content**</p><p>more content</p>`

I also tried an xpath selector `response.xpath('//div[@class="entry-content"]').get()`, but with the same result as above.

Based on F.Hoque's answer below I tried:

`response.xpath('//article/div[@class="entry-content"]//p/text()').getall()` and `response.xpath('//article/div[@class="entry-content"]//p').getall()`

These however, returns arrays of respectively all `p` elements and the content of each found `p` element. I however want the HTML contents (in a single value) of the `div.entry-content` element without the wrapping element itself.

I've tried Googling, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your main div contains multiple p tags and you want to extract the text node value from those p tags. //p will select all the p tags.

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="entry-content"]//p').getall()
```

The following expression will remove the array

```
p_tags = ''.join([x.get() for x in response.xpath('//article/div[@class="entry-content"]//p')])
```

Comment: I added a clarification, I don't want the text content of each p tag, but the HTML contents of the main div

Comment: @Adam remove the //text()

Comment: I tried that, but that still results in an array

Comment: @Adam I've updated

Answer (score 0):

You content is in the `<p>` tag, not the `<div>`

```
response.css('div.entry-content p').get()
```

or

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="entry-content"]/p').get()
```

Comment: Sorry, but my main div contains multiple `p` tags that I want to retrieve, I changed the HTML

Comment: @Adam I don't know what tool you are using, but the css selector should match all the `<p>` tags under the `<div>`. Maybe you need to replace `css()` or `get()` to retrieve multiple tags?